# sympy Matrices within a sympy Matrix remains unevaluated on substitution

Tags: python, matrix, lazy-evaluation, sympy, substitution

While my issue seems linked to the sympy github issue [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6557), it either doesn't seem directly related, or remains an open, unsolved issue (from 2012).

My issue is that I have a 'matrix' (really, it's just a vector but is my only option due to how sympy deals with things) within my matrix represented by a symbol, that when substituted, shows up a matrix rather than evaluating it.

Below is a sample block of code that will demonstrate this:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
x = np.random.rand(15, 3)
l_syms = sympy.MatrixSymbol('l', 1, 3)
m = sympy.Matrix(x/l_syms)
m.subs({l_syms:sympy.Matrix([[1,1,1]])})
```

Each value in the `matrix` [[1,1,1]] should be divided into each element of the `m` matrix, but the matrix sits as-is, with the index notation remaining.

```
Matrix([
[  0.98979011265311*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.833576329284127*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.575808048824554*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.523263044342704*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.320197709246721*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.592365354846089*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.943288501064919*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.996020450969247*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.964522394691641*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.763752929521655*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.690054409108757*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.417629855595703*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.213578356927868*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.362782611339912*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.892921288169683*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.068921237699985*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.244310349677818*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.977494896836049*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[0.0169721915631557*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.254316922886399*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.682785271511585*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.768287921847173*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.679243253034139*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.790710466097621*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.892115183428169*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.988514816033581*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.537769900907173*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.275725750770885*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.928279364723852*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),   0.18023576064915*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[  0.71421202332017*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),  0.663585719630706*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),   0.43460735199406*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.770814091341355*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1), 0.0650430822905173*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1), 0.0845773234523002*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[0.0398441324212175*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1), 0.0358479090409692*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1), 0.0801076763216808*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[  0.89937521111821*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1),   0.21500916688666*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.661216039738327*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)],
[ 0.866641224226343*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 0]**(-1), 0.0506005171711028*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 1]**(-1),  0.791277139679317*Matrix([[1, 1, 1]])[0, 2]**(-1)]])
```

I don't seem to be able to find a way to *evaluate* all those Matrix objects and their indices - the only thing remotely related was the github issue linked above, but using `xreplace` is for my intentions even less optimal/correct, as it leaves the symbol in place rather than substituting the matrix in.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a more relevant issue https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doit` will evaluate the expression

```
In [9]: print(m.subs({l_syms:sympy.Matrix([[1,1,1]])}).doit())
Matrix([[0.391482321650262, 0.261165517803277, 0.142349217414644], [0.273871679444907, 0.753721446526393, 0.915204734923647], [0.689284430582533, 0.509755263016457, 0.828178833602631], [0.258602302969241, 0.561852165820955, 0.926528186168350], [0.932268817842373, 0.275670112515102, 0.313790471533159], [0.815965494794080, 0.00638263457666399, 0.728986133320254], [0.771288596688822, 0.159602759327409, 0.846541783656596], [0.703501924167250, 0.168463436323684, 0.496465192945264], [0.265617558320534, 0.727288058464723, 0.301561940789455], [0.134747729067062, 0.315683443879649, 0.741893699540517], [0.763480667163729, 0.459612818589501, 0.295897102504639], [0.519647253027057, 0.884505816757734, 0.823849322619653], [0.0499379745242409, 0.333299403033741, 0.960531610086280], [0.658552664971765, 0.788381947436270, 0.609862319604282], [0.748840147759344, 0.434013189476355, 0.747584770109250]])
```

Comment: Thanks @asmeurer. I came across this shortly after and forgot to come back here to post the answer.